# Loop through a series of numbers with SET

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SET @YEAR:=2021;
SET @MONTH:=02; 
SELECT *
FROM accounts
WHERE DATE(start) <= CONCAT(@YEAR,'-',@MONTH,'-01')
AND DATE(end) > LAST_DAY(CONCAT(@YEAR,'-',@MONTH,'-01'))
```

Currently I'm changing `@MONTH` and `@YEAR` manually when doing this data pull. Is there any way to put a loop through `SET @MONTH` e.g. SET @MONTH:=1:12 and let it run through all twelve months, with the results compiled together?

Comment: Your `WHERE` clause seems weird. If the constructed date is `2021-07-01`, are you sure that you want to select less than `2021-07-01` and greater than `2021-07-31`?

Comment: please provide sample data and desired output